# Dynamically bind property

Tags: angular

I have this template

```
<div [fromGroup]="myForm">
 <input [formControl]="myFormControl" [formControlName]="formControlName">
</div>
```

I was wondering if I can bind one or the other. For example, if `formControl` has data, them I want to do this.

```
<div>
 <input [formControl]="myFormControl">
</div>
```

But, if `formControl` is empty I want to do this:

```
<div [fromGroup]="myForm">
 <input [formControlName]="formControlName">
</div>
```

Is there a way to dynamically bind a property like that on the same template without a `ngIf`?

Comment: Why are you so against using an if?

Comment: I was wondering if there is another way, that's all.
If I use an `ngIf`, then I have to duplicate the template content

Comment: It would be encouraging to every answering dev when you can give some feedback whether those answers helped you to fulfill your requirements and if so mark that answer as right one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngIf`. Check below link,

[Angular NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: I don't want to duplicate the template content.
React, does this easy, but how can achieve the same on angular?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
 <div [fromGroup]="formControl?null:myForm">
    <input [formControl]="formControl? [formControlName]="formControl? 
    null:formControlName">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `then`-clause and `else`-clause notations in `*ngIf` to show one or several blocks when a condition is `true` or `false`, as it is shown [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#using-an-external-then-template). Assuming that `formControl` is initialized by a truly value then `trueBlock` is rendered, when `formControl` is not initialized by `null` or `undefined` then `falseBlock` is rendered instead:

```
<div *ngIf="formControl; then trueBlock; else falseBlock"></div>
<ng-template #trueBlock>
  <div>
    <input [formControl]="myFormControl">
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #falseBlock>
  <div [fromGroup]="myForm">
    <input [formControlName]="formControlName">
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Not bad :)

But, If want to have 3 or more optional parameters the template becomes a mess.

Comment: I agree, but you can extract this code-snippet and put it into a component. `formControlName`, `myFormControl` and all other form-variables might be added as `@Input`'s.